# Playwright: Find icon by classname in near range of a defined text

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Good evening,

I would like to ask if someone knows, if it's possible in *Playwright* to check if an icon - under certain conditions - is visible?
The conditions are:

- the icon has a specific name, but appears multiple times on the site
- it has to be in a certain range (lets say 15 pixel) of a unique text

My first idea was something like this...

```
await expect(page.locator('icon:near(:text("Specific text"), 15)'))
```

...but as you can see, I miss the option to declare the icons classname

Thanks in advance and have a nice evening.

finethen

Comment: Can you share the piece of html where that element is contained please?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Playwright docs on matching by layout](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#css-matching-elements-based-on-layout), those matchers “can be combined with regular CSS to pinpoint one of the multiple choices.”

If I’m understanding correctly that any css can be used, then you should be able to use the class name just fine. So basing off your example, you should be able to do something like

```
.yourclassname:near(:text("Specific text"), 15)
```

Hope that works for you!